# lftp mget equivalent for put?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, scp

Reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/75681/inverse-multiplexing-to-speed-up-file-transfer/305236#305236), it seems an awesome way of transferring a ton of tiny files between two remote machines is lftp's `mget` command.

However, I'm using two machines without root access, and only the sending machine has `lftp`, and it seems like you can only parallelize receiving through `lftp`.

Is there some way to do something equivalent to a `mput` in `lftp`, or if not, something similar?

Comment: I removed your *"(Also an acceptable answer: is there a way to parallelize `rsync` instances without manually setting each of them up with a bunch of `--include` and `--exclude` flags?)"* — please post that as a separate question, if needed. Main rule on all Stack Exchange sites: one question per post, please.